# Solutions of $x^d=1$ in a finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces, finite-fields

Let's consider the polynomial $x^d-1$. Theory tells us that it can have at most $d$ roots in (any extension of) a given field.

Here's my problem: let $A$ be the vector space spanned by $1,a,a^2,b,b^2,ab$ over $\mathbb{Z}_3$ (the integers mod $3$). $A$ is itself a field if we define $x^i*x^j=x^{i+j\pmod 3}$.

Choosing $d=2$ we should have that, at most, $2$ elements in $A$ should be equal to $1$...but I can count more than $2$ (at least $a^2,b^2,a^2b^2$). May somebody help me to point out the error in this reasoning?

Comment: How do you define multiplication over these vectors?  What is $a \cdot a^2$?

Comment: $a\cdot a^2 = a^{3~mod~3} = a^0 = 1$

Comment: What are $\;a,b\;$ ? And if this is a field, what is the neutral element wrt addition...and *what* is the addition here?

Comment: Addition can be defined as polynomial one, remembering that coefficients are in $\mathbb{Z}_3$, so $\lambda a + \mu a = ((\lambda + \mu)~mod~3) a$. $0$ is the neutral element wrt addition. $a,b$ are two generic elements, their sum remains $a+b$

Comment: @Saphrosit , where did you get this construction from? It's rather confusing (for me, of course. Perhaps not for others). Do you mean you have to take **all** the finite linear combinations of $;1,a,a^2,b...\;$ with coefficients of $\;\Bbb Z_3\;$ ?

Comment: @DonAntonio Sorry if it's confusing, it is just something I thought about while studying finite fields. Yes, I was thinking about all linear combinations with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}_3$, sorry if it's not clear from my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ring you have constructed is not a field, since we have (non-zero) zero-divisors.  Note that
$$
(a - 1)(a^2 + a + 1) = a^3 - 1 = 0
$$
The [unique field (up to isomorphism) of size 27](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field#F27) is given by
$$
F_{27} = \mathbb{Z}_3[t]/(t^3 + t^2 + t + 2)
$$
The ring you have constructed can be thought of as
$$
R = \mathbb{Z}_3[a,b]/((a^3-1)(b^3-1))
$$

Comment: According to what he wrote, *perhaps* he meant a field with $\;3^6\;$ elements, not $\;3^3\;$ ...who knows?

Comment: @DonAntonio I figured the closest approximation for what he was attempting was the field over $\mathbb{Z}_3$ constructed by modding out a cubic polynomial

Comment: @Omnomnomnom thank you very much, you're perfectly right. Can you please show me how did you get to the equivalent formulation for the ring I defined?

Comment: @Saphrosit there's not much to it.  $\mathbb{Z}_3[a,b]$ is the (commutative) ring of all polynomials on $a$ and $b$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}_3$.  In the quotient, I have the "defining relations" $a^3 - 1 = 0$ and $b^3 - 1 = 0$ (verify that $(ab)^3 = 1$ follows).  As in group theory, a (polynomial) ring is completely determined by its generators and some set of relators.  [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12824/do-people-study-ring-presentations-is-this-a-dumb-question) is a decent explanation.