# The quotient ring ${\bf Z}[{\omega}]/(1-{\omega})$ only has 3 residue classes with representatives $0$, $1$, and $-1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I want to prove that any element $a+b{\omega}$ in ${\bf Z}[{\omega}]$ is congruent to either $0$, $1$, or $-1$ in the quotient ring ${\bf Z}[{\omega}]/(1-{\omega})$. Here $(1-{\omega})$ is the ideal generated by $1-{\omega}$. We recall that ${\bf Z}[{\omega}]$ is a Euclidean ring and is hence a principal ideal domain.

My attempt is as follows. I am not entirely sure about my reasoning! In the quotient ring, since $1={\omega}$, $1={\omega}^2$, and so $1+{\omega}+{\omega}^2$ must be $3$. But $1+{\omega}+{\omega}^2=0$ in ${\bf Z}[{\omega}]$ (remember $\omega$ is a complex cube root of unity). Since $3=0$ in this quotient ring, and $\omega = 1$, any element $a+b{\omega}$ must be congruent to $a+b$ modulo the ideal $(1-{\omega}).$ Therefore dividing $a+b$ by $3$ yields one of the remainders $0$, $1$, 0r $-1$. Where am I making a mistake?
*(Perhaps irrationally), I feel uncomfortable about concluding that $3=0$ in the quotient ring.*

Comment: What makes you think you’re making a mistake?

Comment: For a `solution-verification` question to be on topic you must specify *precisely* which step in the proof you question, and *why so*. This site is not meant to be used as a proof checking machine.

Comment: Sorry. Will edit my question underscoring the precise point which troubles me!

Comment: You essentially used $w\equiv 1\Rightarrow f(w)\equiv f(1)\,$ so $\, 0 \equiv w^2+w+1\equiv 1^2+1+1,\,$ which *is* rigorous - being a special case of the  *Polynomial Congruence Rule*, see the linked dupe. $\ \ $

Comment: i.e. we're working modulo the ideal $\,I = (x\!-\!1,\color{#c00}{f(x)}) = (x\!-\!1,\color{#c00}{f(1)}) = (x\!-\!1,3),\,$ by $\,\color{#c00}{f(x)\equiv f(1)}\pmod{x\!-\!1}.\,$ Finally $\,\Bbb Z[x]/I \:\!\cong\, \Bbb Z/3\,$ as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/12713/242). $\ \ $

Answer (score 1):

$(1-\omega)(2+\omega)=2-\omega-\omega^2=3-(1+\omega+\omega^2)=3$, so $3 \in (1-\omega)$.

Comment: Cleared up doubts!! Should I withdraw the question?

Comment: No reason that I can see to do so.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).
It's best for site health to delete this answer (which also minimizes community time wasted on dupe processing.)

Comment: @stu This answer can be viewed more conceptually as computing the norm of $\,1\!-\!w,\,$ i.e. $\,N(1\!-\!w) = (1\!-\!w)(1\!-\!\bar w) = (1-w)(2+w) =  3,\,$ since the conjugate $\bar w$ satisfies  $\,\bar w + w = -\color{#c00}1\,$ by $\,w^2+ \color{#c00}1 w + 1 = 0,\,$ i.e. sum of roots $= -\color{#c00}1\,$ by Vieta. But it is wasteful to compute the "Bezout" coefs $\,g_i\,$ that verify the ideal membership $\,3 = (x\!-\!1) g_1 + f g_2\in (x\!-\!1,f)$ since we need only the "remainder" - not the "quotients", so congruence (or modular) arithmetic is simpler (*much* simpler for larger problems)

Comment: Bill, should I withdraw this question? I genuinely had this doubt, but can see how it could be misinterpreted.

Comment: @BillDubuque (a) When I answered the question (roughly an hour after it had been asked), no one had identified it as a dupe.
$$$$
(b)  Based on the suggested dupe, I still don't think it's a dupe.  Getting from the suggested dupe to an answer to the specific question asked requires some reasoning.  I see the mathematical equivalence, of course, but that doesn't make it a dupe to the question that's been asked.
$$$$
(c) I respectfully suggest that questions tagged as "abstract algebra" are closed as dupes somewhat too frequently, based on concerns similar to those I've expressed here.

Comment: @RobertShore The answer follows immediately by applying the polynomial remainder theorem - as explained in the closing comment on the question.  Said timing does not change the dupe status.